# QGIS select one by one feature in a layer

Tags: qgis, python, select, spatial-query

I'm trying to select features one by one on a layer.

I have a line layer, I've created a buffer layer from this, and then what I want to do is to select one by one feature on the buffer layer, do what I wish to, deselect and go to the next feature.

The reason why I need to select and deselect features is that I'm doing some spatial queries on selected lines.

Comment: Have you tried to use qgis graphical modeler or looping with Python ?

Comment: When I'm trying looping there are 2 options. 
If I have no selection it's just run through my lines but doesn't work because I ask to run through selected features in the spatial query 
I'm using this one

'INTERSECT' : QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(buflayer.id(), True), 


and if I asked to run for all features for each line feature it prints all the point features that intersect.

Comment: What is it you wish to do with the selection? How are you executing the spatial queries, using some geoprocessing tool?

Comment: From the selected line I want to select the points that intersect with that line.
Then, I want to jump to the next line, select it and do the same

I'm using this command 

processing.run('qgis:selectbylocation', parameters)

Comment: I am having difficulties to understand what you need based on your description. Could you give a more detailed and precise description? But by what I understand, Ofir's suggestion using the graphical modeler should work. In the graphical modeler combine the selection with the intersection, and then run it as a batch so it goes through all your features (maybe instead of location you can use an attribute and run through all the attributes)

Comment: FEATURES(lines)--> SELECT ONE--> SELECT POINTS THAT INTERSECT WITH THAT LINE--> CREATE A REPORT--> CLEAR SELECTION-->GO TO THE NEXT LINE AND TO THE SAME etc....till the end of the FEATURES(lines)